# Adding Index to existing DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to coding and have no idea what I am doing. I made this pd.DataFrame and now want to go back and add an index with the values ('Count', 'Volume (R-AMT)', 'DV01')

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
{'RFQ Total - Excluding Pass': [RFQ_count, Vol_RAMT, DV01],
               'Hit Count': [hit_count, hit_count_volume, hit_count_DV01],
                'Hit Ratio': [hit_ratio_count, hit_ratio_volume, hit_ratio_DV01],
                'Cover Count': [1, 1, 1],
                'Cover Ratio': [1,1,1],
                'Tie Wins': [1,1,1],
                'Tie Away': [1,1,1],
                'Tie Ratio': [1,1,1],
                'Revenue': [1,1,1]})
index=['Count', 'Volume (R-AMT)', 'DV01']
df1
```

This is what I have tried, it does not work. I have watched a few youtube videos and read some forums. Now I am here asking for help. Thank!!

Comment: `df1.index = index`?

Comment: Or `df2 = df.set_axis(index)`

Comment: sorry what does this mean exactly? Tried this, but no dice.

df1.index = index('Count', 'Volume (R-AMT)', 'DV01')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try and create a new data frame at the end by replacing the df1 line at the bottom with something like. df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1, index=index). Try and print out df2 to see what it gives you.